# How to handle windows services c# with newer versions of .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, service, frameworks

...

Hi all,

I'd like to create a Windows Service in c#. But I can only choose one of the .NET Frameworks:

```
.NET Framework 2.0
.NET Framework 3.0
.NET Framework 3.5
.NET Framework 4.7.2
.NET Framework 4.8
```

But what I need is `.NET 6.0`. But the Problem is, `.NET 6.0` is allready installed and is usable for console-apps? I have two versions of console-app projekts. One with `(.NET Framework)` and one without. But why I only have `(.NET Framework)` projects for service-apps?

How do you handle services. Do you write all of you app-code into the service? Do you only use the service to run a console app?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd have assumed because when you consider the ecosystem of operating systems on which .net core/5+ apps run, they don't necessarily even have the concept of a "service", which is a windows flavored approach to "an app that runs all the time and mostly is managed by the o/s". However, there isn't any magic to a service per se; it's an exe that is run by the SCM - for years it has been possible to use wrappers that turn ordinary exes into services. Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service)

Comment: Thanks, I had to modify it a little bit, but now it works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of examples, but the main thing is, write a console application and with a hosted service, and add .UseWindowsService() on the end of your Host builder.

https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2019/10/15/windowsservice/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
  Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging(
      options => options.AddFilter<EventLogLoggerProvider>(level => level >= LogLevel.Information))
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
      services.AddHostedService<Worker>()
        .Configure<EventLogSettings>(config =>
      {
        config.LogName = "Sample Service";
        config.SourceName = "Sample Service Source";
      });
    })
    .UseWindowsService();
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to modify it a little bit, but now it works for me